# Запуск скрипта при выполнении условий

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы, если в поле на html страничке ввели **правильный** текст **и нажали** кнопку, то запускается скрипт? 
Хелп >~<

Answer (score 1):

Что-то в этом роде:

```js
function checkText() {
  var a = "то с чем сверяем";
  var b = $('#text').val();
  if(a == b) {
    // Место для вашего скрипта!
  } else {
    alert("Неверно");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="text" />
<a href="#" onClick="checkText()">Проверить</a>
```

Comment: лучше использовать обычную кнопку `<button>` - не было бы перехода

Comment: В целом - да, можно и `<button>` - просто в текущем проекте - много ссылок с действиями jquery - поэтому на автомате воткнул)